# Ngrx observables not reacting to state store change when using Object.assign() in combination with other operations

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I have some trouble understanding why the first sample seems to work ok but the second one has trouble firing the observers.

```
// Working reducer
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    expanded: Object.assign({}, state.expanded, { clients: !state.expanded.clients })
});

// Faulty reducer - Devtools indicates a change but the observables 
// seem to not respond and pass on the information down the line
newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newState.expanded.clients = !state.expanded.clients;


// Selectors
import {createSelector} from 'reselect';
export const SIDEBAR = (state: AppState) => state.sidebar;
export const SIDEBAR_UI = createSelector<AppState, SidebarUIState, SidebarState>(
    SIDEBAR,
    (state: SidebarState) => state.ui
);

// Sidebar service
public getSidebarUIExpandedObservable(): Observable<SidebarUIExpandedState> {
    debug('Get sidebar UI expanded observable');
    return this._store.select(SIDEBAR_UI_EXPANDED);
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Can I accept all three answers?  :D I will wait for a few more votes from public and select the top voted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing :

```
newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newState.expanded.clients = !state.expanded.clients;
```

do

```
return Object.assign(
  {},
  state,
  {
    expanded: Object.assign(
      {},
      state.expanded,
      {
        clients: !state.expanded.clients
      }
    )
  }
);
```

**Trick :** 
When you'll have Typescript >= 2.1.4 you'll be able to do it like that

```
return {
  ...state,
  {
    expanded: {
      ...state.expanded,
      {
        clients: !state.expanded.clients
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Nice use of spread operator. Seems so flush. Actually I am using 2.1.5. so I will get busy refactoring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reducers require pure functions, that make use of immutable objects. 
Hence you cannot mutate the newState object, but you would have to create a new object that has definite new state upon creation.

Your first example fits the immutability principle, because Object.assign copies the matching propertie(s) of the object in the third parameter to a copy of the object in the second parameter, before assigning this to target object (first parameter). Thus, the original state has remained unaffected, and a new state is obtained in the target object. 
In other words, no original object state has been changed by object.assign in memory and the return value delivers a ready to go (no further mutations required ) new state object. 
more info on Object.assign(): https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

In the second case there is a new object created at first (immutability still valid), subsequently, the state is mutated by assigning the boolean, hence the immutability principle is broken, and reducers usually do not accept this.

Answer (score 1):

With the following in a reducer:

```
newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newState.expanded.clients = !state.expanded.clients;
```

the content of `state.expanded` is being mutated.

That is `newState.expanded` and `state.expanded` refer to the same object and that object's `client` property is being mutated. Code looking at `expanded` will see that the object reference is unchanged and will assume that the content has not changed either, but you have mutated it by toggling the value of its `clients` property.